# Dealing with asynchronization in iOS development

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, asynchronous, box-api

I am pretty new to iOS and working in multi-threaded environments in general. I have a comp sci background so you can imagine my dismay upon learning that no one actually uses semaphores to manage threads for an iOS app.

I understand how to use delegates to provide call backs and I am also able to use blocks as well. These work well for some things like making requests for data that might not be immediately available, but I am having trouble when it seems like I need a series of dependent operations.

For instance the problem I am currently struggling with involves using the "Box" API.

I want to:

1. Have my main app able to make calls to a Box manager class and in this case send multiple requests to create remote folders
2. Have each folder be created without the Box manager having to callback the main class every time it successfully creates a remote directory

**The Problem:**

If there are multiple requests to create folders that share a parent directory then only one will create the parent directory and the rest will return a 409 error. The API does not allow you to create a folder from a path like /home/photos/.., you need to provide only a name and the ID of the parent folder it should be created in. The error is indicating that one of the folders already exists (the parent).

The only way I can see to solve this problem is to at least have the first folder with a given parent created before the others. I have read many other threads that say if you are trying to make a series of operations synchronous then you are doing something wrong so my question is where am I going wrong here thinking about this? How should I be thinking about this situation so that I see an asynchronous solution?

Here is the method I am using to try to create the folders:

```
 //Folder Creation
- (void) createFolderFromPath:(NSString *)path
{
    NSArray *pathWithoutRoot = [path pathComponents];
    pathWithoutRoot = [pathWithoutRoot subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, [pathWithoutRoot  count]-1)];
    [self createFolderFromPathComponents:pathWithoutRoot withParentId:BoxAPIFolderIDRoot];
}

- (int) createFolderFromPathComponents:(NSArray *)pathComponents withParentId:(NSString     *)parentId
{
    if ([pathComponents count] < 1)
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;

    NSString *parent = pathComponents[0];
    NSArray *remainder = [pathComponents subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, [pathComponents count]-1)];

    BoxFoldersRequestBuilder *folderBuilder = [[BoxFoldersRequestBuilder alloc]init];
    folderBuilder.name = parent;
    folderBuilder.parentID = parentId;

BoxFolderBlock success = ^(BoxFolder *folder)
{
    NSDictionary *folderInfo = folder.rawResponseJSON;
    [self.treeInfo setObject:folderInfo[@"id"] forKey:folderInfo[@"name"]];
    [self createFolderFromPathComponents:remainder withParentId:folderInfo[@"id"]];
    };
    BoxAPIJSONFailureBlock failure = ^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, NSDictionary *JSONDictionary)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error creating file with dictionary %@",JSONDictionary);
        NSLog(@"Error creating file with error %@",error);
        NSLog(@"Error creating file with response %@",response);
        //Returns a 409, If I could get the ID of the folder  I colided with here that would pretty much solve things,
        //but Box does not send that information

    };

    [[BoxSDK sharedSDK].foldersManager createFolderWithRequestBuilder:folderBuilder success:success failure:failure];
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: There is a difference between synchronous and sequential. If you have a series of operations that need to be completed in a certain order (such as creating a parent folder before creating a child) then that is just the way it is.  You can use a sequential dispatch queue so that the tasks can be queued asynchronously but execute sequentially. You can also analyse your tasks to determine which need to happen sequentially (create the parent before the files) and which can happen in parallel (create the files) and submit the tasks to appropriate types of queue

Comment: If I had to write the code that I write on a daily basis with semaphores, locks etc., I'd go completely mad.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a comp sci background so you can imagine my dismay upon
>   learning that no one actually uses semaphores to manage threads for an
>   iOS app.

The technologies referred to as "Grand Central Dispatch" handle the semaphores for you. You use a higher level abstraction (queues, blocks, groups) instead of semaphores. GCD also deals with the callback pattern for you using blocks with is much less wire up than delegation.

You can use a recursive method to check and potentially create parent folders on a background thread. The success and failure blocks ensure parent folders are created prior to child folders.

```
//This method always returns immediately and uses blocks to inform the caller when finished.
- (void)createFolder:(NSString *)path
         sucessBlock:(void(^)(void))success
        failureBlock:(void(^)(void))failure //Failure only happens due to network or service disruption
{
    //Recursive method does not create root path.
    NSString * rootPath;
    if ([path isEqualToString:rootPath])
    {
        success();
        return;
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
                   , ^{
                       //Insert code to get folder info here.
                       BOOL folderExists = YES;

                       //If folder already exists, send success block. You may want to do this on the main thread depending on your class design.
                       if (folderExists)
                       {
                           success();
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           //Insert code to get parent folder path.
                           NSString * parentFolder;

                           //Now make a recursive method call on the parent folder.
                           [self createFolder:parentFolder
                                  sucessBlock:^{
                                      //This recursive method call will use success block when parent folder tree is established or if it already existed

                                      /*
                                       * Insert actual folder creation code for the path parameter here
                                       */
                                      BOOL succeeded = YES;
                                      if (succeeded)
                                      {
                                          success();
                                      }
                                      else
                                      {
                                          failure();
                                      }
                                  }
                                 failureBlock:^{
                                     failure();
                                 }];
                       }
                   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Important concept number 1 is the runloop. On the main thread, there is a loop running continuously (without using CPU time, and behind your back) that gets notified when events happen and which calls an appropriate method to handle it. That's in principle how MacOS X and iOS applications work. GCD has a function to dispatch code blocks to the queue behind that run loop. So all event handling methods, and all the code blocks dispatched to the run loop, will be executed one after the other.

Important concept number 2 is an infinite number of background threads. GCD has a function to dispatch a block of code to any of the background threads. All these code blocks run in parallel and eventually finish. Now obviously each of these blocks is free to dispatch a code block to the run loop as the last action before it finishes - that's what people do.

You rarely ever wait for one of these blocks to finish, so you very very rarely need semaphores. You never wait for *one* block to finish, because that block just dispatches some block to the run loop when it finishes. If you ever need to wait for two or more blocks to finish, you create a dispatch group which will - guess what - dispatch a block when all blocks dispatched to the group are finished.